# I am trying to delete items from TODO app using axios and django

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am unable to delete items from TODO app. 
I am using react and axios for deleting.
Here is the error I am getting in network tab.

```
Provisional headers are shown
Origin: null
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
```

```js
handleDelete = item => {
  axios
    .delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/todos/${item.id}`, item)
    .then(res => this.refreshList());
};
```

Button:

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(item)} className="btn btn-danger">
  Delete
</button>
```

Here is the screenshot of network tab.[image: network tab]

Comment: That doesn't seem like an error to me. Can you see what initiated the error? It would have got the initiator location in the console.

Comment: Also, can you check the network tab, see what it says, like HTTP Status Code, the DELETE body, etc. or is it just a preflight failure?

Comment: Please have a look on this issue, it might be your case too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin

Comment: @gazdagergo That issue has been closed long back.

Comment: Anyways, Chrome does not allow CORS localhost, and you can handle it installing this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: @gazdagergo Better way to work it in the official method without any plugins: [Using React's Proxy to get ahead of CORS & use HTTPS for API calls](https://blog.praveen.science/using-reacts-proxy-to-get-ahead-of-cors/)... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution for this is to proxy the API Calls for your React App. Create React App provides you with a solution.

Before anything, I would like to tell that this method applies only for the applications that are created using Create React App and also this proxying works only on the development environment as a development feature and is not available for the production build. You just need to add a new key to the `package.json` called `proxy` and then restart the server.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000/",
```

Now, your complete `package.json` file looks something like this.

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

And for the `DELETE` requests, you can just call:

```
handleDelete = item => {
  axios
    .delete(`/api/todos/${item.id}`, item)
    .then(res => this.refreshList());
};
```

The above code will have nothing related to CORS.

From the manual...

> *Keep in mind that `proxy` only has effect in development (with `npm start`), and it is up to you to ensure that URLs like `/api/todos` point to the right thing in production. You don’t have to use the `/api` prefix. Any unrecognized request without a `text/html` accept header will be redirected to the specified `proxy`.*

So it is indeed specific for development purposes and not for a production level use. This helps in working with the future, where there's this similar setup and avoids all the crazy localhost hacky architecture for gearing with the environment.

I wrote a blogpost detailing how to set this thing up - [**Using React's Proxy to get ahead of CORS & use HTTPS for API calls**](https://blog.praveen.science/using-reacts-proxy-to-get-ahead-of-cors/). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Amnahkhatun Then you may be able to access this way right: `.delete(\`/api/todos/${item.id}\`, item)` - This would totally solve the issue.

Comment: yes I have written in the same way. This is what I am getting in response tab :
```
{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
```

Comment: @Amnahkhatun Can you send a screenshot of the network tab contents using imgur?

Comment: I am unable to add images

Comment: @Amnahkhatun It says forbidden. That's weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button>onClick={()=>this.handleDelete(item)}>delete</button>
```

Please not that inorder to prevent automatic button submission, we need to write delete button as mention above